# How do I save a string description to an image document in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, file, save

I'm trying to write some descriptions to image documents for clarification reasons. Is it possible to write descriptions to document files like in Android or not? If so how?

**Developer Note**: For those of you who don't know, saving to the Photos app gives you very limited options. (You can't name your file, change the extension from Jpeg to png, make sub-directories  etc.)

Below is code to save an Image to document directory

//Save Image At Document Directory :

```
  let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + "/swiper.jpg"
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "swiper"), 0.5)
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: path, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
```

Github Link to code:

https://github.com/artemnovichkov/FileSharingExample

Comment: Before, I used Realm alongside saving to the documents directory. In the realm model, I stored the filename + other descriptions and details. But there’s is probably a better way.

Comment: What do you mean with _description to image document_ here, is it the image metadata you want to change? And what is this about not being able to name the file making sub directories etc, of course you can do that. And if you want a PNG file then use the function for that instead of a JPEG function.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson 1. In both Windows and Mac files have a string description attribute.  2. No you can't make and name sub directories in photos. (Ex: I can't have a photo directory named "seasons" and a directory called "Fall" encased in it

Comment: 2. I missed you were talking about the Photos app, now I understan what you mean.